# How to cache data on a form before it is saved?

Tags: c#, caching

I have a little problem with form data caching (keeping it in a variable before it's actually saved to a file). I have a pretty simple form layout:

1. ObjectCombo
2. ParamCombo1
3. ParamCombo2
4. ParamText1
5. ParamCombo3
6. SaveButton

This form is meant to configure certain parameters for specific objects in my program. The list of all the objects is in the ObjectCombo. And the parameters are in the other form fields. Whenever I pick another object from the ObjectCombo I want the parameters entered for that object to be cached until I have configured every object in the ObjectCombo list. After everything is configured I'd like to press the SaveButton so that every cached parameter for every object in ObjectCombo gets saved at once.

My solution this far is that I created a Dictionary with int (index of the object in the ObjectCombo) as key and another dictionary with parameter name as key and parameter value as value.
   `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>`

I will do the caching in ObjectCombo SelectedIndexChanged event and thus when I have configured the last element and clicked Save the last element does not get saved because no SelectedIndexChanged event was fired. Of course I could go back to a different object in ObjectCombo and that would solve the problem but that's not user friendly. Is there a different event I could subscribe to that lets me cache the config data before moving to a different object?

Is my approach to this challenge even reasonable? I've messed around with this problem for a day and everything I've done sounds so simple but since English is not my native language I might have a problem articulating myself. If anyone interested in helping is having problems understanding what I'm trying to achieve don't hesitate to ask more information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way would be keep your data in hidden field `<asp:HiddenField runat="server"/>`, you should create some javascript handlers for fill this hidden field.
It would also be better if you post the code of your project, then I could offer some variant of implementation.

Comment: I guess this solution is not viable in my use case (not a web application).

Answer (score 0):

Best approach for this is to create a clone of each object and add the clones to the combo box. Let the user update all the cloned objects, one at a time. You can hook up events to each parameter control, such as TextChanged for ParamText1. Then, as the events fire you will update the ObjectCombo's selected item (you will need to typecast to your actual type as the apparent type will be object). ObjectCombo's SelectedIndexChanged event should only be responsible for populating the other controls as the user picks a different object. The events for each param control will be responsible for updating the selected object. Make sure you unsubscribe to param control events in SelectedIndexChanged when updating the controls otherwise those events will get fired unexpectedly.

After the user has updated all the (cloned) objects and presses "Save". Simply copy over all the cloned data (aka your cache) to the originals.

The idea behind this is that you are "caching" the user changes in cloned objects and then, once saved, you will copy over the cached data to the actual objects.

Comment: These parameters are not properties or class variables of the listed objects. The objects in question are API objects and I have no access to them.

Comment: Then your question is not complete. Is it an internal API? What exactly are these API objects? How do you fetch/update them? Can you create wrappers for them? You should still be able to accomplish what I described.

Comment: It is Autodesk Revit API. And the objects in question are FamilyType objects. I thought about creating a wrapper class but the parameters I cache are only used in the code for creating some records in our ERP system afterwards. That's the reason I haven't created a wrapper class yet.

Comment: Your best bet, and good practice, is to create a domain model for your UI. The model will be some object (maybe not a wrapper but an object with similar properties). The UI will populate your models which will sit somewhere in a list (UI presenter/controller). Then, once the user is finished populating the objects (e.g. presses Save) you can do whatever you want with them. You can make API calls, use them internally, it doesn't matter. The point is that you are normalizing your application with internal objects then using those objects to send data over to some other system.